# How to build Sitecore SXA Scope Search query with comoperations

Tags: sxa, solr, azure-search, sitecore-query

I have requirement to show the query results based on the logged-in user-profile details, I was able to pass the query token field value dynamical by following the [code](https://ggullentops.blogspot.com/2019/10/sitecore-sxa-search-scope-custom-component.html).

How to write a SXA search scope query in this format

[Company A **OR** Company B **OR** EMPTY] **AND** [Country A **OR** Country B **OR** EMPTY]

Comment: I'm not sure if I get your point... SXA is not using a custom query builder or something similar. If you are not able to compose search query like that in clean sitecore, then you won't be able to do it in SXA either (we are using the same field for queries).

Comment: I want define in scope like  +(country A || Country B) +(Company A || Company B)

Comment: You can check the post https://www.switchit.com/blog/sitecore/extending-sitecore-sxa-search-results.aspx